# ¿Cómo puedo contar comas en una cadena de caracteres en C?

Tags: c

El problema es el siguiente tengo una cadena de caracteres (aaa,bbb,ccc...) y quiero sacar de esa cadena algunos datos, por ejemplo bbb. Se que se puede hacer contando las comas de la cadena, si pasa esta coma coger este dato. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?
La cadena se refiere a un código NMEA de un módulo GPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo contar comas en una cadena de caracteres en C?

Pues recorre la cadena, y cuenta las comas:

```
int comas = 0;

for (int i = 0, e = strlen(cadena); i != e; ++i)
    comas += (cadena[i] == ',');
```

Si quieres separar los valores entre las comas, puedes usar [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

```
for (char *c = strtok(cadena, ","); c; c = strtok('\0', ","))
    printf("%s\n", c);
```

Ten en cuenta que `strtok` modifica la cadena original poniendo `\0` en los puntos en que encuentra el separador.

Pudes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pX62vXODswHQHnlW).

Answer (score 1):

Con esta funcion le indicas cual es el texto y cual es el limitador entre ellos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int dtmsplit(char *str, const char *delim, char ***array, int *length ) {
  int i=0;
  char *token;
  char **res = (char **) malloc(0 * sizeof(char *));

  /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, delim);
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
        res = (char **) realloc(res, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        res[i] = token;
        i++;
      token = strtok(NULL, delim);
   }
   *array = res;
   *length = i;
  return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int c = 0;
    char **arr = NULL;

    int count =0;

    char str[80] = "aaa,bbb,ccc";
    c = dtmsplit(str, ",", &arr, &count);
    printf("Found %d tokens.\n", count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("string #%d: %s\n", i, arr[i]);

   return(0);
}
```

En este caso si lo compilas el resultado será

```
Found 3 tokens.                                                                                                                
string #0: aaa                                                                                                                 
string #1: bbb                                                                                                                 
string #2: ccc
```

Donde podrias tomar el valor cualquiera de los 3 resultados obtenidos en `arr` indicandole la posicion requerida ejemplo `arr[1] // bbb`